# Why is my JS code working only on mozilla?

Tags: javascript, html

I created the `<script>` tag before my `</body>` as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var select = document.getElementById('empresa')
    var value = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value
</script>
```

And I created a select where I'm inserting the options like this:

```
<select name="empresa" id="empresa">
                      <option onclick="javascript: if(value ==  'none'){
                        document.getElementById('umConvite').style.display = 'none'
                        document.getElementById('doisConvite').style.display = 'none'
                        document.getElementById('tresConvite').style.display = 'none'
                        document.getElementById('quatroConvite').style.display = 'none'
                        document.getElementById('btn-confirmar').style.display = 'none'    
                        }" value="none">-----</option>

                    <option onclick="javascript:
                            if(value == 'Empresa 1'){
                                document.getElementById('umConvite').style.display = 'flex'
                                document.getElementById('umConvite').style.flexDirection= 'column'
                                document.getElementById('doisConvite').style.display = 'none'
                                document.getElementById('tresConvite').style.display = 'none'  
                                document.getElementById('quatroConvite').style.display = 'none' 
                                document.getElementById('btn-confirmar').style.display = 'flex'        
                            }
                            " value="Empresa 1">Empresa 1</option>

                    <option onclick="if(value ==  'Empresa 2'){
                        document.getElementById('doisConvite').style.display = 'flex'
                        document.getElementById('doisConvite').style.flexDirection= 'column'
                        document.getElementById('umConvite').style.display = 'none'
                        document.getElementById('tresConvite').style.display = 'none'
                        document.getElementById('quatroConvite').style.display = 'none'
                        document.getElementById('btn-confirmar').style.display = 'flex'
                        }" value="Empresa 2">Empresa 2</option>


</select>
```

This in `Mozilla Firefox` is working correctly, but in chrome and safari it's not working, how could I solve this?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? What happens instead? Nowadays, nobody would write such long code in an `onclick` attribute, but in JS

Comment: why don't you use proper event handling instead of writing all your JS inside an onclick attribute?

Comment: @NicoHaase It just doesn't work in other browsers, but in mozilla it works fine, I'm learning Javascript, could you show me a more practical solution?

Comment: @WPfan see [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Event_handlers#eventtarget.addeventlistener)

Comment: @empiric I'm starting as JS, can you show me an example? I would be extra grateful!

Comment: If you see this code in six months and you think "Oh. My. God." it's a good sign of progression :) Keep learning!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define select option without any JavaScript code And the trigger change event of the select tag and check your condition:

```js
        var select = document.getElementById("empresa");

        select.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
            func(e);
        });
        function func(e) {
            debugger
            if (e.target.value == 'none') {
                alert("none");
                //document.getElementById('umConvite').style.display = 'none'
                //document.getElementById('doisConvite').style.display = 'none'
                //document.getElementById('tresConvite').style.display = 'none'
                //document.getElementById('quatroConvite').style.display = 'none'
                //document.getElementById('btn-confirmar').style.display = 'none'
            }
            else if (e.target.value == 'Empresa 1') {
                alert("Empresa 1");
                //document.getElementById('umConvite').style.display = 'flex'
                //document.getElementById('umConvite').style.flexDirection = 'column'
                //document.getElementById('doisConvite').style.display = 'none'
                //document.getElementById('tresConvite').style.display = 'none'
                //document.getElementById('quatroConvite').style.display = 'none'
                //document.getElementById('btn-confirmar').style.display = 'flex'
            }

            else if (e.target.value == 'Empresa 2') {
                alert("'Empresa 2'")
                //document.getElementById('doisConvite').style.display = 'flex'
                //document.getElementById('doisConvite').style.flexDirection = 'column'
                //document.getElementById('umConvite').style.display = 'none'
                //document.getElementById('tresConvite').style.display = 'none'
                //document.getElementById('quatroConvite').style.display = 'none'
                //document.getElementById('btn-confirmar').style.display = 'flex'
            } 
        }
```

```html
    <select name="empresa" id="empresa">
        <option  value="none">
            -----
        </option>

        <option value="Empresa 1">
            Empresa 1
        </option>

        <option value="Empresa 2">
            Empresa 2
        </option>
    </select>
```

Note that because I don't have complete html (element with `umConvite, doisConvite`.. ids) I just show alert in each conditions.

Comment: You could use `switch` instead of `if...else if...else if...else if...` And also, the click handler could be written more simply `select.addEventListener('change', func);` But I'm nitpicking, this code is already much better. Have an upvote

Comment: @JeremyThille could recommend a good course? I really want to become a good JS developer!